# Array, como aplicar nessa questão?

Tags: javascript, array

Tenho a seguinte questão:

Uma professora de programação, cansada de que os estudantes cheguem tarde, decidiu que vai cancelar a aula se há poucos presentes.

Ela representa a entrada dos estudantes como um `array` de **tempos de chegada** tarde, *em minutos*.

> **Por exemplo**, se um estudante chegou **10 minutos atrasado**, outro **5 minutos antes da hora**, outro com **3 minutos de atraso**, e **outro pontual**, poderá representar assim:
>
> ```
> var alunosDaSegunda = [10, -5, 3, 0];
> ```

Com essa informação e a quantidade mínima de estudantes para que suceda o curso, a professora quer saber se a aula acontecerá.

> **Por exemplo**, supondo que a **quantidade mínima de estudantes** para que a aula aconteça é de **2 alunos**, então o curso da segunda-feira se realizará, porque houve um estudante que foi pontual e um estudante que chegou cedo.
>
> ```
> acontece(alunosDaSegunda, 2)
> // true
> ```
>
> Mas **se a quantidade mínima fosse 3**, a aula não aconteceria:
>
> ```
> acontece(alunosDaSegunda, 3)
> // false
> ```

Escreva as seguintes funções:

1. `acontece`, que diz se a aula sucederá de acordo com o `array` dos estudantes que entraram.
2. `aberturas`, que utiliza um `array` com os arrays dos estudantes que entraram nos outros dias, e a quantidade mínima de estudantes, e diga quais os dias em que as aulas aconteceram e quais não.

   > **Por exemplo:**
   >
   > ```
   > aberturas([alunosDaSegunda, alunosDaTerça, alunosDaQuarta], 2)
   > // [true, false, false]
   > ```

---

<sup>Adicionado como resposta - 14/05/2019 as 22:49</sup>

Gente, não estou conseguindo achar a solução.

```
function acontece(estudantes) {

    var quantidade = estudantes.length;

    var positivos = 0;

    for (var i = 0; i < quantidade; i++) {

        if (estudantes[i] <= 0) {

            positivos = positivos + 1; 

        }
    }
}
```

please como posso acertar ?

Comment: Bem vindo ao StackOverflow em Português. Editei sua pergunta para remover as saudações pois costumamos manter o texto o mais limpo possível para focar na sua dúvida sobre programação. Caso tenha interesse em visitar uma parte do site que não é voltado para tirar dúvidas pode conhecer o [chat]. Se tiver dúvidas quanto ao funcionamento, regras e procedimentos do site visite o [meta] :)

Comment: Alguma resposta ajudou a resolver o problema e pode sanar dúvidas similares de outros usuários? Caso positivo não esqueça de marcar a resposta como aceita. Pra fazer isso é só clicar no ✓ do lado esquerdo da mesma (abaixo do indicador de up e down votes).

Answer (score 2):

```js
function acontece(horario, alunos){
  var qtd = 0;  
  for(var i = 0; i < horario.length; i++){
    if(horario[i] < 1){
      qtd++;
    }
  }  
  return qtd >= alunos;
}

function aberturas(dias, alunos){
var qtd = 0;
  var vet = []
  for(var x = 0;x < dias.length; x++){
    for(var i = 0; i < dias[x].length; i++){
      vet[x] = acontece(dias[x], alunos);
  }
    
  }  
  return vet;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Você vai precisar de uma variável para contar quantos alunos chegaram na hora correta. Essa variável deve iniciar com o valor zero.

Então você deve utilizar o comando for para percorrer o array e utilizar um if para verificar se aquele elemento do array menor ou igual a zero. Caso seja, você incrementa a sua variável contadora.

Ao final do programa você verifica se o contador tem o valor maior ou igual a 2.

Não vou escrever código aqui porque essa é a sua tarefa... ;)

Comment: To tentandoooo ! vamos ver se consigo !

Answer (score 0):

Você pode usar a função filter:

> [`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filtro)
>
> O método `filter()` cria um novo array com todos os elementos que passaram no teste implementado pela função fornecida.

Essa função executa uma outra para cada item, a qual retornará `true` ou `false`. Esse retorno determinará se o item estará em um `array` resultante. No seu caso você deve verificar se o item é menor que zero e comparar o `array` que será formado com o valor mínimo de pessoas:

```js
const acontece = (tempos, minimo) => tempos.filter((tempo) => tempo <= 0).length >= minimo;
const aberturas = (dias, minimo) => dias.map((dia) => acontece(dia, minimo));

console.log(acontece([10, -5, 3, 0], 2));
console.log(acontece([10, -5, 3, 0], 2));
console.log(aberturas([[10, -5, 3, 0], [10, -5, 3, 1], [10, 1, 3, 0]], 2));
```

Para a função `aberturas` você só precisa executar a função descrita anteriormente (`acontece`). O método mais eficaz para realizar isso retornando um `array` é pela função [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map).

---

> [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)
>
> O método `map()` invoca a função `callback` passada por argumento para cada elemento do Array e devolve um novo Array como resultado.

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta, porém só posso usar for -> if e function, estou tentando bolar na base que me passou !

Answer (score 0):

Como você só pode usar for e if, segue abaixo minha solução:

```
function acontece(estudantes, minimo) {
    var quantidade = 0; //variável contadora
    for(var i = 0; i < estudantes.length; i++) {
        if(estudantes[i] <= 0) { //compara se o estudante [i] chegou na hora
            quantidade++;
        }
    }
    return quantidade >= minimo; //condição booleana
}

function aberturas(dias, minimo) {
    var respostas = []; //array de respostas
    for(var i = 0; i < dias.length; i++) {
        respostas[i] = acontece(dias[i], minimo);
    }
    return respostas;
}

console.log(acontece([10, -5, 3, 0], 2)) //true
console.log(acontece([10, -5, 3, 0], 3)) //false

console.log(aberturas([[10, -5, 3, 0], [10, -5, 3, 0]], 2)) // [true, true]
console.log(aberturas([[10, -5, 3, 0], [10, -5, 3, 0]], 3)) // [false, false]

</code>
```

Answer (score 0):

Você tem que criar uma função que verifica um array especifico depois cria outra que chama a primeira e verifica vários arrays. Assim:

```js
    function acontece(arr, num) {
      if(arr.length < num ) {
        return false;
      }

      let presentes = 0;
      for(let i=0;i<arr.length;i++) {
        if(arr[i] <= 0){
          presentes += 1;
        }
      }

      return (presentes >= num);
    }

    function aberturas(arr, num) {
      let arrAcontece = [];
      for(let i=0; i<arr.length;i++){
        arrAcontece.push(acontece(arr[i], num));
      }

      return arrAcontece;
    }
```